# Fixed two-column positioning of consecutive <div>s

Tags: css

I have three consecutive `<div>`s which need to be positioned in two columns with the first `<div>` occupying the first column and the rest occupying the right column, as in the below image and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx6VJ/). In the jsfiddle I'm using a `width` constraint to force the `float`s into position. Could this be accomplished in another way and without using a `width` constraint? The order of the `<div>`s can't be changed.

[image: layout]

I'd prefer a solution that uses as few fixed `<div>` widths as possible.

Comment: Are the elements guaranteed to have a specific height?

Comment: If `#container` div has definite width and height set, you can use absolute positioning to arrange 3 divs inside it. I see other options to implement it but please provide us more information on what restrictions are applied to container.

Comment: @cimmanon `<div>` elements will have varying heights. Widths  should be the same by column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help offered by @Amit and @user1823713 I used a combination of their answers to get something that keeps the `<div>`s' relative position and adapts their width to the width of the container. Here's the resulting [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEsMA/).

This layout can be plugged into a container without any changes, with eventually a single width set on the container to constrain the total layout width.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `float` from the right divs, and add a `margin-left` slightly larger than the width of the left div - http://jsfiddle.net/cx6VJ/2/

If you don't want a fixed width for the left div, you can set both the width and the margin-left in percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixed positioning and percentage widths to do it.

CSS Code:

```
.image {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:75%;
    height:100%;
}
.summary {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:75%;
    width:25%;
    height:50%;
}
.info {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:75%;
    width:25%;
    height:50%;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. `<div>` heights may vary due to content. How could this solution be adapted so that `.info` always is directly below `.summary`?

Comment: fixed positioned `<div>`s will have fixed width and height even if percentages are used.

Answer (score -1):

I'm only providing this because it was asked for:

> I'd prefer a solution that uses as few fixed  widths as possible.

Here's a solution with no divs (it uses a table):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ma9EE/

```
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="2">Image</td>
  <td>summary</td></tr>
  <tr><td>info</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the `<div>` tags.

Comment: That looks like a table used for layout rather than for expressing tabular data.

Comment: @seron -"Unfortunately I can't change the <div> tags"   Really?  Why not?

Comment: @Steve Because the HTML tags are generated by a system (WooCommerce, an e-commerce plugin for WordPress) I have limited control over.

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox might be an ideal choice for this, but support isn't widespread yet.  You can do this with `columns` if you don't mind that it doesn't work in IE9 or older.  You'll need to add prefixes for Mozilla and Webkit.

http://jsfiddle.net/cx6VJ/4/

```
#container {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 408px;
    columns: 2;
}

#container > div {
 /*   break-inside: avoid-column;*/
}

#left {
    border: 2px solid green;
    min-height: 200px;
    break-after: column;
}

.right {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
}

#red {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

I've deliberately made the `right` elements smaller than your demo, but you can increase their size to 200px and they'll still have the desired layout.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn